# Bunny Hop, Stoppie or Wheelie? Which one to attempt first on MTB?

Tags: mountain-bike

I am 21 years old. I'm overweight for my age..171 ibs. I have started cycling few months back and I'm lovin' it. I have a Merida mtb(mainly used on the road)

I was thinking about practicing some basic mtb stunts mentioned above. Can I do those with my overweight body? If yes, then what should I attempt first.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you must mean that you are overweight for your height? Anyways, this question doesn't really fit the format of this site. Short answer, attempt them all!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Overweight is relation to height rather than age, but that really isn't an issue at all with performing "stunts". I am 175 and was in the x-games performing "stunts". The most useful "stunt" in the sport (that I can think of ATM) is the bunnyhop! This basic maneuver is the one that will get you further in this sport than almost anything else. You can get over curbs, rocks, rivers, cracks, etc. Wheelies are cool and help in skatepark contests, and for a short distance might help with getting up on things, but it is really just the first step in a bunnyhop. Wheelies are the only trick where weight can be a factor since you will be torquing your chain, but that shouldn't matter in your decision (going up hills does the same thing). Endos (stoppies) are not practical for anything I can think of except to practice front end balance. Bottom line: LEARN BUNNYHOPS FIRST!!

Comment: Thank you very much. This really answered my question. Now, time to get ready for some bunnyhop. Again, thank you very much. :)

Comment: Hi, a question if you don't mind, you were in the X-games with BMX or MTB? Also, is it possible to see your x-games stunts? :)

Comment: 1998 for BMX, and I didnt record it and I wasn't good enough to get my runs televised... hahah!!

Comment: stoppies are VERY useful for nose press! ([video](http://video.mtb-forum.it/videos/view/1556))

Comment: ...and nose-picks, and rock walks, and nose-blunts/bonks, nose-wheelies, hang nothings, squeak-scoots...